# XML node cannot traced

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

A web-service returns a XML over SOAP and I am trying to parse it. However I cannot reach nodes. I trace XML at all but nodes are untraceable.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SbDrsRprRspnse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <SbDrsRprRslt>
                <SODSRprDt>
                    <Aktiv>false</Aktiv>
                    <Silindi>false</Silindi>
                    <Sira>0</Sira>
                    <Numara>IL1</Numara>
                    <AdSoyad>Maksim Tsygalha</AdSoyad>
                    <ToplamEtk>30</ToplamEtk>
                    <TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk>
                    <Durum>20</Durum>
                    <Units>
                        <SbOgrtDSUnitRDt>
                            <Aktif>false</Aktif>
                            <Silindi>false</Silindi>
                            <UnitsAdi>Ünite 3</UnitsAdi>
                            <EtkTop>30</EtkTop>
                            <TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk>
                            <Durum>20</Durum>
                        </SbOgrtDSUnitRDt>
                    </Units>
                </SODSRprDt>
            </SbDrsRprRslt>
        </SbDrsRprRspnse >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can `trace(returnXML)` and see all things above. But when I try `trace(returnXML.children().children().children())` it shows nothing. Also `==null`, `==undefined`, `==" "`, and `==""` returns false. What am I doing wrong?

---

edit

here is what I did after the comment;

```
private function ProcessXML(ref:XML):void
{
    var returnXML:XML = new XML(ref);
    var soap:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
    trace(returnXML.soap::Body.SbDrsRprRspnse.SbDrsRprRslt.SODSRprDt.Aktif); //it returns nothing!
}
```

---

edit #2
I am using Flash Builder and it keeps throwing error for second namespace `childrenNs` - `TypeError: Error 1080 - Illegal value for namespace`. I have searched a little bit about the error but couldn't find something worthwhile. So maybe using a one `namespace`-`soap` just for testing that there is nothing else problematic. So is it possible to use only one namespace with this XML?

Comment: To access those nodes you need to apply the correct namespace (soap). That namespace is defined: "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" so apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the namespaces used in the xml. Please, check my code and pay attention to the comments:

```
var testXml:XML = new XML('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SbDrsRprRspnse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SbDrsRprRslt><SODSRprDt><Aktiv>false</Aktiv><Silindi>false</Silindi><Sira>0</Sira><Numara>IL1</Numara><AdSoyad>Maksim Tsygalha</AdSoyad><ToplamEtk>30</ToplamEtk><TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk><Durum>20</Durum><Units><SbOgrtDSUnitRDt><Aktif>false</Aktif><Silindi>false</Silindi><UnitsAdi>Ünite 3</UnitsAdi><EtkTop>30</EtkTop><TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk><Durum>20</Durum></SbOgrtDSUnitRDt></Units></SODSRprDt></SbDrsRprRslt></SbDrsRprRspnse ></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>');

// Here we take the main xml namespace
var soap:Namespace = testXml.namespace();
trace("The main xml: " +testXml.soap::Body);

// Here we take the main xml for the children
var childrenNs:Namespace = testXml.soap::Body.children()[0].namespace();

// When we have the main namespace and the children namespace,
// we may get information about children
trace("The first child: " + testXml.soap::Body.childrenNs::SbDrsRprRspnse);

// We may even set the children namespace as the default namespace
default xml namespace = childrenNs; 
// And after that we can work with children without the namespace
trace("The first child with default namespace: " + testXml.soap::Body.SbDrsRprRspnse);
trace("The Aktif child with default namespace: " + testXml.soap::Body..*.Aktif);
```

**UPD 25-11-2015:**

Also you may try to remove all information about namespace and work with the xml as with a regular xml:

```
var testXml:XML = new XML('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SbDrsRprRspnse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SbDrsRprRslt><SODSRprDt><Aktiv>false</Aktiv><Silindi>false</Silindi><Sira>0</Sira><Numara>IL1</Numara><AdSoyad>Maksim Tsygalha</AdSoyad><ToplamEtk>30</ToplamEtk><TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk><Durum>20</Durum><Units><SbOgrtDSUnitRDt><Aktif>false</Aktif><Silindi>false</Silindi><UnitsAdi>Ünite 3</UnitsAdi><EtkTop>30</EtkTop><TamamEtk>6</TamamEtk><Durum>20</Durum></SbOgrtDSUnitRDt></Units></SODSRprDt></SbDrsRprRslt></SbDrsRprRspnse ></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>');

var testXmlString:String = testXml.toXMLString();
var regExp1:RegExp = /([<\/])(\w+\:)/g;
var regExp2:RegExp = /\sxmlns[^"]+"[^"]+"/g;
testXmlString = testXmlString.replace(regExp1, "$1");
testXmlString = testXmlString.replace(regExp2, "");
trace("testXmlString: " + testXmlString);

testXml = new XML(testXmlString);
trace("testXml.toXMLString(): " + testXml.toXMLString());
```

Comment: Note that the namespace is persistent even across scopes so what's missing in the answer is that the namespace must be removed after you are done with it to avoid conflicts: default xml namespace = null;

Comment: @BotMaster Thanks for the note!

Comment: @MarkDolbyrev is there a way to use only one namespace? Flash Builder is throwing error for `var childrenNs:Namespace = testXml.soap::Body.children()[0].namespace();` _illegal value for namespace_.

Comment: @Jamiryo Please, could you tell more about the problem? Do you work with the same XML as before? Did you work with Flash Builder before or you've just changed your IDE and FB starts throwing the error?

Comment: @Jamiryo I've just updated my answer, please, could you check it?